# Matlab deployment with financial toolbox?

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-guide

I am compiling a matlab code to exe and it has the uicalendar function in it. I did put the main app as my main .m file and in the setting I checked the financial toolbox.
The file compiled successfully and I can run the GUI but when I press the button that calls the uicalendar, the calendar will not show up.

Any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you compile the [example uicalendar application](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/releases/R2011a/toolbox/finance/f11-191444.html#f11-1077999) successfully?

Comment: yes it is compiled successfully and working as a standalone app, just the calendar is not showing up when pressing the button that calls it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [page](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/compiler_support.html), all GUI tools provided by the Financial toolbox (including `uicalendar`) are not supported by the MATLAB compiler for deployment.

Maybe you should search the File Exchange for an alternative...